# When trying to register a UDF using Python on I get an error about Spark BUILD with HIVE

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud

Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o54))

This happens whenever I create a UDF on a second notebook in Jupyter on IBM Bluemix Spark as a Service.

Comment: Can you provide the code which raised the error message ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IBM Bluemix Spark as a Service,  execute the following command in a cell of the python notebook :

!rm -rf /gpfs/global_fs01/sym_shared/YPProdSpark/user/*spark_tenant_id*/notebook/notebooks/metastore_db/*.lck

Replace *spark_tenant_id* with the actual one. You can find the tenant id using the following command in a cell of the notebook:

!whoami

Answer (score 0):

I've run into these errors as well. Only the first notebook you launch will have access to the hive context. [From here](http://quabr.com/34705886/multiple-spark-applications-with-hivecontext)

> By default Hive(Context) is using embedded Derby as a metastore. It is intended mostly for testing and supports only one active user.